# When to start or form a teamfight group?

Tags: league-of-legends

In league of legends you always hit a point where just laning is not profitable enough anymore or it's to dangerous. So many players (obviously) team up and attack with multiple players in a single lane. So team-fights are started. My question would be; is there any sort of criteria for players to make the (game-changing) decision to team up and focus lane or ganks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With good map awareness and lane control, you're going to want to extend the lane phase as long as possible.  Controlling this phase allows you to deny the enemy xp/gold, while reaping it all for yourself.

**Generally once the outer towers have fallen, it becomes dangerous to lane.**  Its a long run to the inner towers from the middle of the lane, and it gets expensive placing enough wards to give you warning. At this point its safer to roam in groups.

There is a bit of fluidity to the decision to stop the lane phase, and it really depends on what's going on around you.  Once you've destroyed the outer tower in your lane, push the lane then leave and help another lane.  Return if you're in danger of losing your tower, or if the lane is totally undefended and you see an opportunity to take the inner tower.

If you're happily farming your lane and the enemy groups up to take a tower, you generally have to respond in kind, by either defending that tower with equal numbers, taking a tower in another lane, or going after a contested objective (dragon, their blue/red buffs).  If the enemy then decides to abandon their attempt and go back to farming lanes, you should probably do so as well.

Comment: although i agree with the pushing up the tower and then going for ganks, im afraid i disagree with you on your last statement. If the enemy goes back to laning after you have their outer tower down thats the ideal timing for ganking right?

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma Well not really, because you've already pushed 1 lane so you can't gank that lane. So that leaves 2 lanes, both lanes will either quickly push their creeps and recall or play very defensively. Which makes it rather hard to start ganking. Best is to return back to the lanes farm for a short period and then redo.

Comment: @Lyrion but if the enemy have no outer tower left isn't it easy'er to gank them seeing as they have to run way further to escape?

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma True but I have never seen a champ stick close to a dying tower tho, when it is about to fall they go to their second tower to protect themselves. Like wise enemy champions in other lanes that overextended will pull back right after the other lanes towered dropped. Thus leaving no one to gank...

Comment: I do like to drop a note that when multiple lanes (preferable all 3) are winning and pushing their lanes, it will be safe to continue laning. Once the one player leaves their lane to push an other lane, the jungler can help back up that lane (map control!) and in meanwhile, the one left behind on the lane can continue pushing that lane for hopefully another tower.

Comment: @MarcoGeersma The decision to go back to your lane in that situation was meant to imply that both towers in the lane had not fallen yet;  The enemy team had tried to group and push a tower, your team grouped and stopped them, they gave up and went back to farm lanes, so you went back to farm lanes in response.  Obviously if towers are down, the situation changes.

Answer (score 1):

The first teamfight should start **when one or more towers are down and player that destroyed tower(s) can roam freely**.

If this doesn't happen then teamfights should be when the **dragon is up and killable**.

If this doesn't happen then teamfights will be when the **next global objective** will be attacked. It is crazy when teams don't fight for Baron or their own Inhibitor.

---

Early game. You focus on CS and not being ganked. You don't care about teamfights.

- All towers up.
- No roaming.
- Level before 6 - Why this? Global ultimates like from Twisted Fate, Shen or Karthus make roaming possible.
- Anti gank ward focus, wards near lane.

Mid game. You start to roam or you prepare to teamfight. **Here you start to form teamfight group!**

- First lane of towers are gone.
- Dragon agressive warding or **teamfight**.
- **Mid or Top are roaming**.
- Anti roam ward focus, wards near blue and red buff.

Late game. **Teamfights**, Baron buff and long respawn timers decide about wining or losing.

- At last Inhibitos is open.
- No one care much about "their" lanes.
- Moving as a group. Fighting as a group.
- Global objectives focus, wards near Baron and Dragon.

Comment: Ok so if for example the enemy top got fed by ganking mid, do you engage in a teamfight then?

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma you have 2 viable options. First - top should push lane so hard that enemy must go back, if they go roam you must puhinsh them by taking global objectives. Second - you should engage 4/5 vs 1/2 and shutdown feed top. This will start teamfight phase in the game because enemies will not go alone after such fight.